# Twit package doesn't return full tweet

Tags: node.js, twitter

When I console log a Tweets `text` attribute that I got from the `stream` functionality of the Twit package it returns strings like these: (I've replaced the links with a other URL)
‌‌‌‌

> "When corruption, sedition, tyranny and treason like this happened in
>   France and America in the late eighteenth cent…
>   https://randomlink.com"
>
> "@AhmedBaba_ @realDonaldTrump Did ya happen to notice the \" mark's?
>   This would imply that his tweet is in fact someo…
>   https://randomlink.com"

At first appearance it seems fine, but most tweets cut of early and contain a "…" before the URL that it contains, when I look at the tweet object I can't find any attributes that actually contain the full tweet. How would I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in :
[Tweet updates Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates.html)

"text" field is truncated to 140 characters

Included is new "extended_tweet" field in payload, containing:

- full_text
- display_text_range
- entities
- extended_entities

In order to access it you should specify tweet_mode=extended parameter