# Twit Get Tweet is Truncated

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am developing a twitter bot that needs to get a tweet by it's id.

Sometimes, when I tried to get a tweet, it would get truncated. Ex. https://twitter.com/thomas_neitmann/status/1297588999884812288

After doing research, I came across this post: [Twit package doesn't return full tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738617/twit-package-doesnt-return-full-tweet)

Where would I put the tweet_mode=extended parameter mentioned in the other post?

EDIT:
Here is my current code:

```
T.get('statuses/show/:id', { id: '1297588999884812288' }, function (e, d, r) {
    console.log(d); //I then handle the tweet

})
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're currently using?

Comment: Thanks, I showed how I am getting the tweet.

Comment: Are you using Twitter's API V1 or V2? Edit: Actually looks like extended_tweet isn't a thing in V1, so I'm assuming you're using V1. What is your resulting query URL looking like? Based on the linked question I expect you just need to add "&tweet.fields=extended_tweet" to your query URL although I'm not sure the specific syntax for how you're calling it with .get()

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm a little confused by what you are asking. I'm using the Twit package, it handles all the API calls for me. I was just wondering if there was a setting or something I had to turn on in my get request to get the full tweet. I'm not aware of any query URL that I am using.

Comment: Oh - sorry, I didn't realize you were using that package. Also I had to leave. 

Looks like Twit is somewhat of an abandoned project at this point, that isn't to say you can't make it work, but I'd recommend looking for something better taken care of then that. 

Looking real quick you might check out: https://github.com/draftbit/twitter-lite